# DRY up gulp tasks

Tags: javascript, gulp

Say I have these two gulp tasks:

```
gulp.task('js.task1', function() {
  return gulp.src(config.js1.src)
  .pipe($.plumber())
  .pipe($.if(production, $.uglify()))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(config.js1.dest));
});

gulp.task('js.task2', function() {
  return gulp.src(config.js2.src)
  .pipe($.plumber())
  .pipe($.if(production, $.uglify()))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(config.js2.dest));
});
```

They're both identical aside from the `src` and `dest` locations.

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
function jsMoveGeneric(src, dest) {
  return gulp.src(src)
  .pipe($.plumber())
  .pipe($.if(production, $.uglify()))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(dest));
}

gulp.task('js.task1', jsMoveGeneric.bind(null, config.js1.src, config.js1.dest));
gulp.task('js.task2', jsMoveGeneric.bind(null, config.js2.src, config.js2.dest));
```

Comment: Yes, have you tried it?

Comment: Yup, just did to verify and it does in fact work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't even need to complicate it that much. Your two function bodies are almost identical, save a few parameters.

```
function uglyPlumber(src, dest) {
  return gulp.src(src)
    .pipe($.plumber())
    .pipe($.if(production, $.uglify()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dest));
}

gulp.task('js.task1', function() {
  return uglyPlumber(config.js1.src, config.js1.dest);
});

gulp.task('js.task2', function() {
  return uglyPlumber(config.js2.src, config.js2.dest);
});
```

Remember that passing strings (or objects) and returning promises works just fine in JS, so you can move the body into a more general function and return the results from there. So long as you return the output of that function from the task, gulp does not know or care what was actually called.

If you know you'll always pass an object with `src` and `dest` properties, you can take advantage of that to do:

```
function uglyPlumber(path) {
  return gulp.src(path.src)
    .pipe($.plumber())
    .pipe($.if(production, $.uglify()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dest));
}

gulp.task('js.task1', function() {
  return uglyPlumber(config.js1);
});
```

There's also an emerging pattern with gulp to isolate tasks into their own modules (files) when they start to become complex, so you can write some of these as helper functions in a file of their own and `require` that. This can be useful when you have a complicated build, as it allows you to unit test parts of the build script.

Comment: Your example does work though, you just don't need to return `uglyPlumber` in a function. Using `.bind` reduces the need for wrapping the argument in a function. Did you check my theoretical example (which I've since tested and verified that it works)? Definitely marking this as the answer though since it works :D!! I also like the idea of breaking generic tasks into modules, that would reduce 400+ line gulp files. It's a better step in the right direction from my proposed question.

Comment: `return` is simpler (and probably faster) than `.bind`. I've had cases where I needed to loop over a set of paths or globs, which bind will not work for, so I'd suggest using the more idiomatic return consistently.