# How to pass object to gulp task to be able to run that task synchronously?

Tags: javascript, build, gulp

I have two gulp tasks

```
gulp.task('build:dev', ['task1', task2', task3'], () => {
  doCssmin({'destination': ['file1', 'file2']});
});


gulp.task('build:prod', ['task1', task2', task3'], () => {
  doCssmin({'destination': ['file3', 'file4']});
});
```

Now I have `cssMin` task which is shared between `build:dev` and `build:prod` so I created that as a function to share with both of them.

```
function doCssmin(files) {
  _.each(files, function(val, key) {
    gulp.src(val)
    .pipe(minifyCss({compatibility: 'ie8'}))
    .pipe(rename(basename(key)))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dirname(key)));
  });

}
```

and `doCssmin` accept `files` parameter as `build:dev` and `build:prod` they have different files to minify css. If I run `build:dev` or `build:prod` `doCssmin` will be run asynchronously. But `doCssmin` depends on `task2`.

My question is how do I extract `doCssmin` to a gulp task and accept `files` parameter so it can be shared with `build:dev` and `build:prod` tasks?

Not sure if it's too confusing?

Comment: I answered almost the [exact same thing yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33395213/dry-up-gulp-tasks/33395314#33395314). Does that help you at all?

Comment: Thanks for the super fast reply, checking it out now.

Comment: If this isn't the same, you may need to loop into Gulp's array support (you can return an array of things) and the `done` callback that tasks can take.

Comment: Just one quick question, if my `doCssmin` has a loop do I return inside the loop or outside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yesterday, I [answered a question on making your Gulp tasks more DRY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33395213/dry-up-gulp-tasks/33395314#33395314). I believe a good chunk of that answer applies here as well.

To support loops with that, you want to merge the streams that you receive from `gulp.src`. Using [the example here](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/using-multiple-sources-in-one-task.md):

```
gulp.task('test', function() {
  var bootstrap = gulp.src('bootstrap/js/*.js')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/bootstrap'));

  var jquery = gulp.src('jquery.cookie/jquery.cookie.js')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/jquery'));

  return merge(bootstrap, jquery);
});
```

For an array, you can use `Array.prototype.map` to convert the items into streams, then merge all of those:

```
function minifyCss(paths) {
  return merge.apply(this, paths.map(function (path) {
    gulp.src(path)
      .pipe(minifyCss({compatibility: 'ie8'}))
      .pipe(rename(basename(path)))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(dirname(path)));
  }));
}

gulp.task('test', function () {
  return minifyCss(['foo', 'bar']);
});
```